# Unable to display labels properly under each button?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display the label under each button. I have 3 button with 3 labels ..one for each button, I am trying to inline each label under button if the length is great than the button it should go to the next line, i am trying to do this for all the 3 lines. I tried a bit of CSS but does not work ? Can someone suggest me what should i consider ?

html

```
   echo '<input type=submit class=btn  id=\"'.$row['UniqueAdvertisingCode'].'\" value=REDEEM    > ';
   echo '<input type=submit class=btn id=\"'.$row['UniqueAdvertisingCode'].'\"  value=BUY       > ';
   echo '<input type=submit class=btn id=\"'.$row['UniqueAdvertisingCode'].'\"  value= POUCHIT > <br>';

   echo ' <label class=lbl>Select Redeem when ready to use coupon at location</label>   ';
   echo ' <label class=lbl>Select Buy when ready to purchase product at location</label>   ';
   echo ' <label class=lbl>Save coupon for later</label>   ';
```

css

```
  <style>
  .btn {
    width: 15em;  height: 4em;
   }


   .lbl{
       width: 15em;   height: 4em;

   }
  </style>
```

Comment: For security reasons, it is best practice to enclose all HTML attribute values in quotations.

Comment: What is shown under “html” is not HTML but some code that is meant to generate HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to define a width for each button, this seems to work:

```
<label class="lbl">Select Redeem when ready to use coupon at location</label>
<input class="btn" value="Redeem" type="submit" id="redeem">

<label class="lbl">Select Buy when ready to purchase product at location</label>
<input class="btn" value="Buy" type="submit" id="buy">

<label class="lbl">Save coupon for later</label>
<input class="btn" value="Pouchit" type="submit" id="pouchit">
```

And in the CSS:

```
.btn {
  height: 4em;
  width: 15em;
}
.lbl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4em;
  width: 12em;
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FwhvR/1/

**UPDATE:** Here's an updated fiddle to address the concerns [from the comments] about smaller screen widths:

http://jsfiddle.net/FwhvR/2/

Comment: If you are asking a question to OP then make this as a comment rather than an answer!

Comment: The code fails badly unless the browser window is fairly wide.

Comment: Actually the code does exactly what it should. It's the layout that breaks badly.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
echo ' <label class="lbl">Select Redeem when ready to use coupon at location</label>';    
echo '<input type=submit class=btn  id="'.$row['UniqueAdvertisingCode'].'" value="REDEEM"><br>';
echo ' <label class="lbl">Select Buy when ready to purchase product at location</label> <br>';
echo '<input type=submit class=btn id="'.$row['UniqueAdvertisingCode'].'"  value="BUY"> ';
echo ' <label class="lbl">Save coupon for later</label> <br>  ';
echo '<input type=submit class=btn id="'.$row['UniqueAdvertisingCode'].'"  value= "POUCHIT" > <br>';
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8dreP/)

**Note:** Just because of css height of your buttons are too much so they are not looking good.